# How can I force a user to be logged off a specific time when they are using a RemoteApp?

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2016, login, remoteapp

I have some RemoteApps that require all users to be logged out for a backup of the database to be able to be made. The issue is that sometimes a user will work very late and not log out.

When the person who's job it is to make the nightly backup goes into do that, they can not as those users are still flagged as active.

I have timeout policies in place for Idle Sessions via a GPO, but we have seen it where that doesn't take effect in time prior to the Backup Window.

I am looking for a solution where I can FORCE the users to be logged out at a certin point in time, to clear out the seats in the RemoteApp.

I understand I can set Logon Hours and then have a GPO enforce that, however, I have not gotten that work work within my world. I am not sure if it is due to the fact my end users are working in a RemoteApp or what.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Set their active session time limit. Then set their logon hours. Then schedule your backup accordingly.

Example:

Logon hours - 8 AM to 6 PM.

Active session tile limit: 2 hours

Backup Schedule: 9 PM

So, a user who logs on at 5:59 PM would be logged out of their session at 7:59 PM. The backup would then run at 9 PM.

This isn't elegant, but it would work.

Comment: Ok, but if a user logs in at 8:00am to start thier work day, won't they be logged out by 10am if the active session limit is set to 2 hours? That won't fly for my end users... They will work from 8am to 6pm with only a 1 hour lunch break. Am I not understanding something here?

Comment: You're understanding it correctly. As I said, it's not an elegant solution. Unfortunately there isn't any other way to force the user session to be terminated.